# Kubernetes - The best way to detect API version when the API had a breaking change, but did not bump the API version

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes made a breaking change in 1.14 -> 1.15.
The type of `MutatingWebhookConfiguration.webhooks` was changed from `Webhook` to `MutatingWebhook` which has additional fields. However the API version has not been changed and remains `v1beta1`.

How can I detect the new API version?

[MutatingWebhookConfiguration in v1.14](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#mutatingwebhookconfiguration-v1beta1-admissionregistration-k8s-io)

[MutatingWebhookConfiguration in v1.15](https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#mutatingwebhookconfiguration-v1beta1-admissionregistration-k8s-io)

[Webhook](https://v1-14.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#webhook-v1beta1-admissionregistration-k8s-io)

[MutatingWebhook](https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#mutatingwebhook-v1beta1-admissionregistration-k8s-io)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `kubectl api-versions` to see the available API versions.

Alternatively, you can run:

```
for kind in `kubectl api-resources | tail +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'`; do kubectl explain $kind; done | grep -e "KIND:" -e "VERSION:"
```

This command will list all the resource types with their latest supported API version when needed.

Of course, you can always check the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-reference).

Also, you may want to use [kubectl convert](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#convert) in order to convert config files between different API versions.

Comment: I'm not sure this fixes my issue: As I mentioned in the question: "However the API version has not been changed and remains v1beta1".